# Kendo UI Grid, restful URL and paging

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a web service from which I get text which is parsed into `JSON` using `$parseJSON` from *jquery*.

A client can get data from the web service by doing loading `http://myserver/myfunction/{pagenumber}/{pagesize}`

This will return an object

```
{
total: <some int> //A number indicating the total number of records
rowsForPage: [......] //An array with just the rows for the requested page
}
```

How can I use this endpoint as a datasource for a Kendo UI grid which will pass the page number and page size for the selected page.

For the life of me I cannot figure this out, but I would think this should be relatively simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            serverPaging: true,
            schema: {
                data: function(data) {
                    return data.rowsForPage;
                },
                total: function(data) {
                    return data.total;
                }
            },
            transport: {
                read: "http://myserver/myfunction"
            }
    }
);
```

As far as the url goes you have to parse out the url parameters skip and take to identify which records you should be passing back. If your page size is 100 and your page is 3 then it should pass

```
skip=200&take=100
```

Comment: I think the question is more about how do you set the url read path `myserver/myfunction/100/200` without overwriting the read value just before calling the server. I know how to do this for non-rest calls by setting parameterMap property of the datasource, but what if you need to modify the url, how do you tell datasource to append your params as url.